# How to get the load time of each and every single element present on webpage of a site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, load

How to get the load time of each and every single element present on webpage of a site.

For getting the page load time we can use this :

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get(urls[i]);

long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = (finish - start)/1000;
```

But this is not a good idea to calculate load time of every image, css and js rather than we can use "http://www.webpagetest.org/".

So at last my question is how I can perform above task using selenium webdriver?

Comment: You don't really want to get the load time of every single element on the page... what are you actually trying to do? You can use the Network tab in Chrome devtools to see when the DOM is loaded, etc. That's more likely a better and more reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not the good tool to get the load time of any element, as you can see in selenium doc findElement(By by) is itself having some wait time.

**[WebElement findElement(By by)](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)**

Find the first WebElement using the given method. This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the time of execution. The findElement(..) invocation will return a matching row, or try again repeatedly until the configured timeout is reached. findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

I suggest you can use jmeter to get it. :)

Comment: Ya through jmeter and many other are there through which i can get the load time like "http://www.webpagetest.org/" to get the load time of each and every element present on webpage. But my question is that can i do this using selenium ????

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Selenium. There's no legitimate reason I can think of where you would need the load time of every single element on the page. In the time that it took you to look up a couple elements, all the elements would be loaded.

You are better off looking at measuring how long it takes the DOM to load, etc. and you can do that in the Network tab of the Chrome devtools or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Inspect element" option in Google Chrome, or firebug in Firefox.
Then you have to click on "Network", you just have to refresh the page and you'll see a timeline which shows you the loadtime of all scripts and other files.

Edit: Sorry I saw your question is in case of Selenium webdriver, I have no experience with that.